# Workaround or alternative to Samba on a non-Linux machine

Tags: samba, file-sharing, smb, cifs

This territory Is new to me, I am looking to implement Samba in a non Linux machine. From what I read I can see that Samba is only be applied on Linux machines. Is there any workaround to have Samba/SMB working on another operating system. Perhaps any alternative solutions to Samba?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by non Linux machine, Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** Samba is actually a compatibility layer for Microsoft Windows Network.

Samba is a free software re-implementation of the *SMB/CIFS* networking protocol, SMB is mostly used with windows and is the standard solution for windows networking.

So if you mean Windows, if you have it set up properly it should just work.

Comment: I have a set up of 2 operating systems. One is VxWorks and the other is ThreadX. I want to share my files from the VxWorks "server" to the ThredX "clent" and allso be able to see the Windows' folers as well (which already has a standart solution as mentioned.

Comment: I think mentioning you want top do this on RTOS would have been beneficial ;) Maybe even a tag or two.  
Anyways, this is probably not a programming question so I think you will end up on either SuperUser, ServerFault or Electronics StackExchange site.  
You should also add to your question what is it exactly zou want to achieve, I don't think Samba is the solution here.